# encode a perfect json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i have this code

```
$md_query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC";
$md_result = mysql_query($md_query, $con);

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');

while($md_row=mysql_fetch_array($md_result))
    $data_row = array(
        'id' => $md_row['id'],
        'type' => $md_row['type'],
        'title' => $md_row['title'],
        'content' => $md_row['content'],
        'author' => $md_row['postedby'],
        'post_date' => $md_row['posteddate'],
        'publish' => $md_row['publish']
    );

print json_encode($data_row); `
```

but I only show 1 record... does anyone how to fix this?

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Don't use [`SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299); select only the columns you need.

Comment: You are resetting $data_row in every iteration. All you need to do is to store all the row to an array and `json_encode($final_array)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your row-records like {row1: {a:b, b:c}, row2:{e:f, g:h}}

```
$json = '{';
while($md_row=mysql_fetch_array($md_result)) {
$data_row = array(
    'id' => $md_row['id'],
    'type' => $md_row['type'],
    'title' => $md_row['title'],
    'content' => $md_row['content'],
    'author' => $md_row['postedby'],
    'post_date' => $md_row['posteddate'],
    'publish' => $md_row['publish']
);
$json .= '"' . $id . '" :' . json_encode($data_row) . ','; 
// $id just as an example for the string-value pair
}
$json = substr($json, 0, -1); // remove comma after last row
$json .= '}';
echo $json;
```

For more examples also see:

http://json.org/

http://json.org/example.html

Comment: an array of object should be encapsulated in []. As @user1083183 answered the final output should be `[{id:1,title:'title'},{id:2,title:'title2'}]`

Comment: neither did the OP ask for an array of object nor do I see user1083183's answers... wrong topic?

Answer (score 5):

Your while loop doesn't include the print statement... so, it loops through all the records, completely resetting `$data_row` each time, and then prints it once when it's done.

To include multiple statements you need to use `{` and `}` to encapsulate the block.

Comment: Just add a comma on each pass. However, you'll need to ensure that you don't add a comma to the last record; trailing commas cause issues in some browsers.

Comment: !yeahh the i mean each array 

`{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"me"
},
{
  "id":"2",
  "name":"you" 
}`

i mine no comma show.. between `{},{}`

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through your data and setting `$data_row` to a new array for each row, but you aren't doing anything with it until you exit the loop.

Comment: @HannibalBurr - After the first time through the loop, just print a comma before printing the next array. You can set a flag before the loop to indicate first time through and clear it each time after the prints.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it so overly complicated to display all the rows, or wrap with {}? Just make `$data_row` a multi-dimensional array and json_encode() will do it for you with []:

```
while($md_row=mysql_fetch_array($md_result))
$data_row[] = array(   // please note I added [] !
    'id' => $md_row['id']
    ,'type' => $md_row['type']
);

print json_encode($data_row);
```

Prints e.g:

```
[{"id":"3","type":"One"},{"id":"8","type":"Two"},{"id":"9","type":"Three"},{"id":"10","type":"Four"}]
```

If you convert that JSON string back to array it looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [type] => One
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [type] => Two
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [type] => Three
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [type] => Four
    ))
```

Answer (score -1):

The code sample only prints `$data_row` after the loop has finished, at which point `$data_row` holds the last row from the result. You need to either collect the rows into a data structure, JSON-encode and print it, or print each row with each iteration of the loop.

```
...
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$md_query = $db->prepare(
    "SELECT id, type, title, content, postedby AS author, 
            posteddate AS post_date, publish
       FROM posts 
       ORDER BY id ASC");

try {
    $md_query->execute();
    echo json_encode($md_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    ...
}
```

Note that as this fetches all rows from the table, it will likely exhaust either the maximum allowed memory or run time for the script. If the memory limit is a problem, change the line of code that's responsible for displaying the result so as to print the result a chunk at a time. For example:

```
    ...
    $md_query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo '[';
    $last = $md_query->rowCount()-1;
    foreach ($md_query as $i => $post) {
        echo json_encode($post);
        if ($i < $last) {
            echo ", ";
        }
    }
    echo ']';
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    ...
```